# How to unsubscribe from event Action with parameter when I don't need the parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem/curiosity and couldn't find a better solution anywhere.

I am working on a Unity game and suppose I have a class where I declare an event and invoke it

```
ClassA : MonoBehaviour

public static event Action<string> LevelCompletedEvent; 

public void LevelCompleted()
{
   LevelCompletedEvent?.Invoke("Good job!");
}
```

I want to use this event in 2 other classes that will listen for it.
In ClassB I am using the parameter to output the message in the UI.

```
ClassB : MonoBehaviour 

OnEnable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += DisplayMessage;
}

OnDisable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent -= DisplayMessage;
}

private void DisplayMessage(string message)
{
   //display the message in the UI
}
```

However in ClassC I don't need the incoming parameter "message". I only need the event to know that it was completed.

```
ClassC : MonoBehaviour 

OnEnable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += PlaySound;
}

OnDisable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent -= PlaySound;
}

private void PlaySound()
{
   //play a sound
}
```

The problem is that it won't let me subscribe to the event because the handler doesn't have the same signature. So I tried to subscribe to it using an anonymous delegate.

```
ClassC 

OnEnable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += delegate { PlaySound(); };
}

OnDisable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent -= delegate { PlaySound(); };
}
```

Seeing that this works, I have used this method a lot but recently learned that it doesn't actually unsubscribe from the anonymous delegate and that I should keep a reference to it.

So I changed it to

```
ClassC 

private Action<string> LevelCompletedNewDelegate;


OnEnable(){
  LevelCompletedNewDelegate = delegate { PlaySound(); };
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += LevelCompletedNewDelegate;
}

OnDisable(){
  ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent -= LevelCompletedNewDelegate;
}
```

Now this works but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.
I have a lot of events and I don't really like that I have to declare a new Action delegate on the listener's side.

Is there a better way to do this ?

The easiest way that I found is to just create a new Action event and invoke that for ClassC, like:

```
ClassA : MonoBehaviour

public static event Action<string> LevelCompletedEvent; 
public static event Action LevelCompletedPlaySound; 

public void LevelCompleted()
{
   LevelCompletedEvent?.Invoke("Good job!"); //used by ClassB
   LevelCompletedPlaySound?.Invoke(); //used by ClassC
}
```

This way I could have an event for each class but again, I'm not sure if this way is better. Feels a bit redundant. What do you think?

Comment: The simplest option is probably to use a method group conversion as in your `DisplayMessage` example, include any parameters required by the event, but then just ignore them in the implementation.

Comment: I've tried this version also but it's kind of messy. Imagine that instead of that string message I have 2/3 parameters that are custom types and I send a bunch of stuff to my SoundManager which doesn't needs it. I was curious if there's a cleaner way to do this, but thanks for your input! :)

Comment: You would wrap your 2/3 parameters into an object type, any listener should comply with the e ent signature. If you dont need it, dont use it, but keep it simple

Comment: Tip: if you can, avoid commentary about the question itself, and focus on the subject matter. Adding apologies for a confusing title, or commenting on the length of the question, or hoping that the reader can understand you, or expressing advance thanks, etc. are all not germane to the question. Technical writing is preferred here - it is not jut about ease of understanding now (to help you) but ease of understanding to many future readers (who can learn from your question and its solutions).

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to an event action anonymously like

```
ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += message => { PlaySound(); };
```

And when you do this you don't have to unsubscribe to that event in `OnDisable()`. It will be `Garbage Collected` by Unity when scene change.

But you have to keep in mind when subscribing anonymously that you cannot `Unsubscibe` to an event if you have to do it else where in you code. If you must unsubscribe you have to follow your approach in `Class C`

Official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events) says

> You cannot easily unsubscribe from an event if you used an anonymous
> function to subscribe to it. To unsubscribe in this scenario, go back
> to the code where you subscribe to the event, store the anonymous
> function in a delegate variable, and then add the delegate to the
> event. We recommend that you don't use anonymous functions to
> subscribe to events if you have to unsubscribe from the event at some
> later point in your code. For more information about anonymous
> functions

Comment: I have tried doing this but I am getting the error: "delegate Action<string> does not take 0 arguments". Ah..I had to do: ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += (message) => { PlaySound(); }; This method is nice but I am not sure if it will work when I change to a different scene. Can the application still crash if I do this?

Comment: Yes, it will work, and I don't think the application will crash, the anonymous subscription will be `GC`ed by Unity when the scene unloads or changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most optimal and readable way is using a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) parameter

```cs
public class ClassC : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent += PlaySound;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ClassA.LevelCompletedEvent -= PlaySound;
    }

    private void PlaySound(string _)
    {
        //play a sound
    }
}
```